# VM2 optional objects freezzing

Tags: node-vm2

VM2 out of the box provides a very strict contexts isolation. Including wrapping all the objects with proxies and making them freezed

Is it possible optionally disable such high restricted isolation in case just a simple context. isolation is needed?